# Difference between Windows Embedded Compact 2013 and Windows Embedded 8

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded-8

I have some quires regarding WIN CE.

Is there any difference between Windows Compact Embedded and Windows Embedded edition?

In the website i saw a new version of WIN CE, WIN CE 2013. Is win CE 2013 and Win embedded 8 the same. What are the differences?

We are planning to use this in a hand held device with industrial standards where real time operation is not necessary. For the mentioned application which is the best, Win CE 2013 or Windows Embedded 8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442494/windows-ce-or-windows-embedded-standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Embedded 8 is a stripped down version of Windows 8, Windows Embedded Compact 2013 is a real time OS.

As for which os is the best we needed a realtime os for our industrial application and it has been a pain in the ass, if you don't need a realtime os then I would go with embedded.